# Is there a slam-based alignment using point cloud?

Tags: alignment, point-clouds, lidar, slam

I'm looking for a slam based alignment code to get me started with my project. I'm only intested in LiDAR (point cloud) slam based alignement and not camera!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=lidar+only+slam gives lots of recent works. You can also google for LOAM  (Lidar Odometry and Mapping).

Comment: @datjko I'm not sure LOAM is the answer for this! I'm looking to do alignment on the vehicle. LOAM does mapping and not used for sensor alignment as I understand.